# Golang SSH client error "unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain"

Tags: go, ssh

For some reason Golang SSH client can't connect to my EC2 instance. It throws the following error:
`ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain`

This is my code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/helloyi/go-sshclient"
)

func main() {
    client, err := sshclient.DialWithKey("ip:port", "ubuntu", "my_key.pem")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    out, err := client.Cmd("help").Output()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(string(out))
}
```

What's interesting is that when I ran this code on my other computer the connection was made without any errors. So I think it must be a problem with the PC and not my code. I also tried connecting to the instance in Python using Paramiko client and it worked flawlessly. Of course I tried connecting using `ssh` command in CMD and MobaXTerm client - both worked. I tried using other Golang SSH client `golang.org/x/crypto/ssh` and it didn't work (same error).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, it was an issue with `go.mod` file. Both `golang.org/x/crypto` and `golang.org/x/sys` were outdated, once I updated them it started working. Thanks @kkleejoe for your help.

Comment: Can I know which versions you using now?

Answer (score 1):

assume you can `ssh user@host` without password, public key may be `~/.ssh/id_rsa` or `~/.ssh/id_ecda`

```
import "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
import "io/ioutil"
import "strconv"

func DialWithPublickey(addr string, port int, user, publickeyfile string) (*ssh.Client, error) {
    key, err := ioutil.ReadFile(publickeyfile)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    signer, err := ssh.ParsePrivateKey(key)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", addr+":"+strconv.Itoa(port), &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User:            user,
        Auth:            []ssh.AuthMethod{ssh.PublicKeys(signer)},
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.HostKeyCallback(func(string, net.Addr, ssh.PublicKey) error { return nil }),
    })
    if client == nil || err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    client.SendRequest(user+"@"+addr, true, nil) // keep alive
    return client, nil
}
```

try `DialWithPublickey(host, port, user, "~/.ssh/id_rsa")`

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'm using Windows, my private key is called "my_key.pem" and is in the same folder as my program so using `~/.ssh/id_rsa` just throws an error that this path doesn't exist. After tweaking your code a bit to make it use the public key in my directory it still throws an error `ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain`. Like I said, my code works just fine on my laptop so I think it must be an issue with my computer.

Comment: can you ssh user@host ?

Comment: Nope, I get `Permission denied (publickey)`.

Comment: I waited some time, looking for answers, ran it again and it worked. Now I made another folder, copied and pasted **exactly** the same code and it didn't work. What is going on?!